# UWP: Updating a Background in an ItemTemplate based on a condition

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

In a UWP project a `ListView` is bound to a collection `player` objects. Each `player` object has a property such as `HighScore`. The `ItemTemplate` of the `ListView` shows the `HighScore`for each player. I want to change the `Background` of the `Grid` in the `ItemTemplate` that shows the `HighScore` when it's HighScore matches the `BiggestScore` (a property of the Page's `DataContext`). This represents the largest score across all players. `BiggestScore` is updated after the `HighScore` is set.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Here is some example code which hopefully illustrates the various pieces.

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="root" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView x:Name="lvwPlayers" ItemsSource="{Binding Players}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid x:Name="grdHighScore" Background="Yellow">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding HighScore}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

CODE BEHIND:

```
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        var allPlayers = new AllPlayers();

        allPlayers.Players.Add(new Player(100));
        allPlayers.Players.Add(new Player(112));
        allPlayers.Players.Add(new Player(1160));
        allPlayers.Players.Add(new Player(122));

        this.DataContext = allPlayers;
    }
}
```

PLAYER:

```
    public class Player : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string caller = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Player( int high)
    {
        HighScore = high;
    }

    private int _highScore;
    public int HighScore
    {
        get { return _highScore; }
        set
        {
            _highScore = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

ALLPLAYERS:

```
   public class AllPlayers : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<Player> Players { get; set; }

    public AllPlayers()
    {
        Players = new ObservableCollection<Player>();
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string caller = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void ChangeScore(int playerIndex, int highScore)
    {
        Players[playerIndex].HighScore = highScore;
    }

    private void UpdateBiggestScore()
    {
        BiggestScore = (from player in Players select player.HighScore).Max();
    }

    private int _biggestScore;
    public int BiggestScore
    {
        get { return _biggestScore; }
        set
        {
            _biggestScore = value;

            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create property in your DataContext saying whether HighScore is bigger than BiggestScore, eg. bool IsBiggest

Bind it:

```
Background={Binding IsBiggest, Converter=HighScoreToColorConverter}
```

where YourConverter may be something like:

```
public class HighScoreToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var isBiggest = (bool)value;
        var color = isBiggest ? new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red) : new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
        return color;
    }

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var color = value as SolidColorBrush;
        if (color != null)
        {
            return color == new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @RTDev, thanks for the reply. If you are suggesting putting IsBiggest on the `player' class, then this won't work as `player` objects don't have access to the Pages' `DataContext i.e. can't get BiggestScore, so it can't evaluate IsBiggest. Is there some way to get BiggestScore to the converter?

Comment: hmmm your're right. Not sure if you can do this without avoiding to manually keep only one player to have IsBiggest property set true. Conver takes only one value parameter, so you can't make any comparison there (HighestScore with current Player.HighScore) without storing the HighestValue in some static property in static object and refering to it from Converters ctor to make comparison with the current value but it won't be the nicest solution.

Comment: It's a shame UWP is so restrictive compared with WPF.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the Background Color as a Property to your Player

```
private SolidColorBrush _backgroundColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
public SolidColorBrush BackgroundColor
{
    get { return _backgroundColor; }
    set
    {
        _backgroundColor= value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

and bind it to the Background of the Grid

```
<Grid x:Name="grdHighScore" Background="{Binding BackgroundColor}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding HighScore}"/>
</Grid>
```

When you update the Biggest Score, get the player Object with the biggest score and update the Background. Also change the background of all other players back to Yellow.

Comment: Hi @Thomas Schneiter, thanks for reply. I did think of something similar, but was hoping for a 'cleaner' solution where I didn't have to iterate through all the other players and 'reset' there backgrounds.